# PDF script return value of last non blank field in a group

Tags: javascript, pdf

Trying to teach myself javascript I can do some minor scripts by myself but this one has got me stumped. I have been trying for weeks and cant get anywhere.[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0favH.png)

MY goal is to have the field labeled end item automatically populate with the last item filled in on the list.

I know how to do this in excel but with javascript I am completely lost any guidance would be greatly appreciated thanks in advance.

I have tried this before:

```
    var one = this.getField("a1"); 
    var two = this.getField("a2"); 
    var three = this.getField("a3"); 

//for all 25 fields

 if(two.value==''||two.value==null){
this.getField("a1")} 
    else if (three.value==''||three.value==null){
this.getField("a2")} 

//for all 25 fields
```

Comment: write code snippet you have tried

Answer (score 1):

The loop shown below loops over all of your fields. As long as it finds a value, it remembers that value (so "theResult" always contains the currently last found item). If no value is found (in other words, if we find the last item in the list, we simply break and know that "theResult" contains the last real value.

```
// Start by not having any result
var theResult = null;

// Loop over all fields
for (var theIndex = 1; theIndex < 26; theIndex++) {

    // get this field
    var theField = this.getField( "a" + theIndex );

    // If this field has a value, take it, if not quit our loop
    if (theField.value) {
        theResult = theField.value;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```